Christmas Western with "Nick"
Somewhere between 3 and 6 years ago (2018 to 2021) in December on one of those 'all western' stations, possibly Grit, I saw a Christmas movie which featured a character 'Nick' who was clearly supposed to be saint Nicholas, though if I recall correctly he denied it.
I think it was in color, but I seem to recall the color being washed out like it was from the early days of color films or maybe a pre-HD TV movie.  I came in partway through, but at that point the male main character and Nick were in the wilderness trying to get the main character home.
At the end he finally does and he is about to introduce Nick to his family, only to find Nick has disappeared. I vaguely recall them getting some detail about Nicholas of Myra correct in a throwaway line, though I cannot recall what.

Please review Tips for asking Movie/TV Identification questions

I'm at a loss why people are trying to close this. Are they thinking that there are going to be many Christmas westerns where Santa is in disguise?

Such questions could be answered by ChatGPT.

@Rahul - ChatGPT has a terrible track record with story-identification. It has a strong tendency to 'hallucinate' potential (but totally incorrect) answers. I did a very informal study here; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13985/20774

@Rahul - I just asked ChatGPT to identify this movie. It suggested it was "The Christmas Kid", got the year wrong and then totally invented a plotline that perfectly matched the description by rearranging the words.

Could it be The Christmas Secret (2000)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Christmas_Secret https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0272046/reference/

@Valorum: Totally agree. My point was, since identification question has been made out of topic, the question might receive downvotes and close votes.

@Rahul "since identification question has been made out of topic, the question might receive downvotes and close votes." ID questions have been on-topic for months now.

@galacticninja. Definitely not.  Took me a bit to get a better summary of that https://countdownuntilchristmas.com/the-christmas-secret-aka-flight-of-the-reindeer/ , but it bears no resemblance once you do.

@AlantarH Watch the movie on YouTube, just to be sure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drTWvH0RGAU

@galacticninja  Took a quick look.  No it's not that.  There were definitely no flying reindeer in the movie I'm thinking of.  No trappings at all other than what I mentioned.
